# Facebook PHP SDK searching for posts within time-frame

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am attempting to fetch all posts and respective comments of a user within a certain time frame and I am having trouble finding the fields for the FB SDK. I see the "until" option but I do not see a usage/explanation of it.

```
me/posts?fields=object_id,shares,source,story,to,link&limit=10
```

I want to add a field that only collects posts between two dates. I will then get rid of the limit field. Any suggestions/resources will be great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The information can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api

A time-paginated edge supports the following parameters:

Until : A Unix timestamp or strtotime data value that points to the end of the range of time-based data

Since : A Unix timestamp or strtotime data value that points to the start of the range of time-based data.